# How do I convert a Markdown document with Japanese to Beamer?

Tags: macos, pdf, markdown, pandoc, beamer

For example, I have this Markdown document:

```
## Markdown test

Japanese 日本語
```

I run:

```
pandoc mwe.rmd -t beamer -o mwe.pdf --latex-engine=xelatex -V mainfont=MS\ Mincho
```

The words 日本語 simply disappeared in the resulted file. If I don't use the Beamer template then it works correctly.

I don't have to use `pandoc`. Anything that gets me from Markdown to PDF (slides) on a Mac (with MacTex) would work for me.

If there is no easy solution, I'd be okay with anything that results in non-Beamer PDF slides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you ***do*** have installed a font named *`MS Mincho`* on your system, and it shows up when your start the *`Font Book.app`*? (Looks like, otherwise your "normal" PDF output wouldn't work, but you said it does...)

There are various options to check and verify, which exact font name you should use.

### 1. `Font Book.app` (GUI application)

1. Start *`Font Book.app`*.
2. Type `mincho` into the top right search box.
3. All installed fonts with *'Mincho'* in their names show up.
4. Click on one of the font faces (***NOT*** the main entry!) in the list.
5. A font sample will be displayed.
6. Click on the button with the little ***`i`***-logo.
7. The font's metadata will display.

From the font's metadata you can infer the *`PostScript name`* and the *`Full name`* of the font. Both should work with XeLaTeX. (I usually put quotes around font names with spaces: `-V mainfont="YuMincho Medium"`

Here is a screenshot with the relevant parts of the `Font Book.app` UI highlighted in red. Sorry, I do not have `MS Mincho` installed, I can only show it with another font:

[image: Font Book.app, screenshot]

### 2. `fc-list` (command line utility)

1. `fc-list` is a command line utility that is available via the MacPorts *`fontconfig`* package.
2. If you have it installed, use it.
3. To get a list of font names available for XeTeX, you can simply run:

   ```
   fc-list -f "%{family}\n"
   fc-list :outline -f "%{family}\n"
   ```

   The second command suppresses the listing of bitmap only fonts. Such fonts are unusable for TeX. -- For some more verbosity, and a nice formatting of the info, you could also run:

   ```
   fc-list :outline -f "  family: %{family}\nfullname: %{fullname}\n    file: %{file}\n\n"
   ```
4. To get a list of names containing *'Mincho'*, run:

   ```
   fc-list -f "%{family}\n" | grep -i mincho
   ```

## Change your setup

Now that this smaller problem (*"Which font names should I use?"*) is out of the way, lets deal with your main one:

- **The Pandoc Beamer template (and standard Beamer itself) does not use the `\setmainfont` command.** Therefor putting `-V mainfont=...` onto the Pandoc command line does not do anything.

You can check this by querying the default internal template used by Pandoc to produce beamer output:

```
$ pandoc -D beamer | less
```

Search for a `$mainfont$` variable in there and you'll find none!

You have to modify your setup a bit to get success:

1. **First**, create a simple text file named `mincho.tex` with the following two lines of content (I'm using ***my*** Mincho font name here, so I can really test if my advice will work):

   ```
   \usepackage{xeCJK}
   \setCJKmainfont{YuMincho Medium}
   ```

   The `xeCJK` package is required by XeLaTeX for supporting Japanese (and Chinese+Korean) fonts.
2. **Second**, add `-H mincho.tex` to the command line so the above code snippet is included into the LaTeX code generated by Pandoc.

   This is the complete command to convert your Markdown to Beamer-PDF:

   ```
   pandoc                   \
      mwe.rmd               \
     -t beamer              \
     -o mwe.pdf             \
     --latex-engine=xelatex \
     -H mincho.tex
   ```

---

**Result (screenshot):**

[image: mwe.pdf (screenshot)]

The fonts used by the Beamer-PDF are these:

```
$ pdffonts mwe.pdf

  name                                type         encoding    emb  sub  uni  objID
  ----------------------------------- ------------ ----------- --- ----- ---- -----
  TZVOMD+LMSans8-Regular-Identity-H   CID Type 0C  Identity-H  yes  yes  yes   7  0
  WMSBXQ+LMSans12-Regular-Identity-H  CID Type 0C  Identity-H  yes  yes  yes  30  0
  FXCTKJ+LMSans10-Regular-Identity-H  CID Type 0C  Identity-H  yes  yes  yes  32  0
  NXJKDD+YuMin-Medium-Identity-H      CID Type 0C  Identity-H  yes  yes  no   34  0
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed write-up! One minor further step for me is that I didn't have `everypage.sty`. After getting it, `pandoc` worked perfectly. I do have `MS Mincho` btw.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle btw, more recent pandoc default template does have the `CJKmainfont` variable...